# C# Error About UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, networking, copy, acl

I want to copy file to networking drive.But it show error : C:\pdf.zip has denide (copytonetworkingdrive function).
So I want to change file ACL (copyfileto function).

Problem

1.) I can not access c:\pdf.zip

2.) I can not copy file c:\ to networking drive.

3.) I can not change file access control.

4.) I can not access \\networkingdrive\\blablabla$

( I has login by user via programming [look at logonuser function] )

I develop on windows 7 64bit, VS C# 2012, .Net Framework 4.0.

```
using Ionic.Zip;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Management;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
```

My Code :

```
private static void copyfileto(string fin, string fout)
{
       int i;
       FileStream fsin, fsout;
       *FileSecurity files = File.GetAccessControl(fin);*
       WindowsIdentity self = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
       FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule( self.Name, FileSystemRights.FullControl,AccessControlType.Allow);

       AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = files.GetAccessRules(true,true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
       files.AddAccessRule( rule );

       fsin = new FileStream( fin ,FileMode.Open);
       fsout = new FileStream( fout ,FileMode.Create);

       do 
       { i = fsin.ReadByte() ;
         if ( i != -1 ) fsout.WriteByte((byte) i );
       } while ( i != -1);

       fsin.Close();
       fsout.Close();

}



 private void copytonetworkdrive()
   {
      AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
      IntPtr hTokenLocal;
      if (LogonUser(frm_main.myapp.gl_login_user_for_attachment.ToString(),
          frm_main.myapp.gl_folder_attachment_server.ToString(),
          frm_main.myapp.gl_pass_user_for_attachment.ToString(), LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out hTokenLocal))
      {

         //if (hToken != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(hToken);
         //if (hTokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(hTokenDuplicate);
         WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(hTokenLocal);
         WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();

         copyfileto("C:\\Pdf.zip",frm_main.myapp.gl_folder_attachment_server.ToString() +@"ZIP\quotation\Pdf.zip");
      }
   }
```

In *FileSecurity files = File.GetAccessControl(fin);* 
Error :

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024891
  Message=Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Security.AccessControl.Win32.GetSecurityInfo(ResourceType resourceType, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections accessControlSections, RawSecurityDescriptor& resultSd)
       at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
       at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean isDirectory)
      ...
```

Please Help and Thank.

Comment: Have you tried to run your software as administrator?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? That you do not have access to that folder, or that you cannot change the access rights? If it is the latter please provide some information about what problems you have with that. Furthermore, I doubt, that you can change the access rights for a folder impersonating the user which currently has no access to it.

Comment: Yes I run program with Administrator Level.

Comment: I can copy pdf.zip to network drive and do something. But I can not do it with programming.

Comment: If I move c:\\pdf.zip to d:\\pdf.zip. My program can access file but I can not make sure about drive in user computer.I want to use c:\ path.